# how to switch multiple function ontouchlistener in android

Tags: android, layout, switch-statement, android-view, ontouchlistener

[image]

I have two ontouchlistener function which is drag and drop and resize function . i want to make it if i onclick button drag and drop button it can perform drag and drop ontouchlistener, if i click on resize button, it can perform reize ontouchlistener function. is it make sense to use switch case in this case? Sorry for my english, hope can understand my question

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {
    Button psave;
    TextView textView3;
    public static final String PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = "MyAppPreferences";
    private int xDelta;
    private int yDelta;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)h.findViewById(R.id.RLtab3);
        textView3 = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Button btnAddARoom = new Button(getActivity());
        btnAddARoom.setText("Test");
        btnAddARoom.setOnTouchListener(this);
        rl.addView(btnAddARoom);


        return h;
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.move:
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        xDelta = X - Params.leftMargin;
                        yDelta = Y - Params.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -50;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -50;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
                return false;
            case R.id.tresize :
                int x=(int)event.getX();
                int y=(int)event.getY();
                int width= view.getLayoutParams().width;
                int height = view.getLayoutParams().height;


                if((x - width <= 20 && x - width > 0) ||(width - x <= 20 && width - x > 0)){
                    switch (event.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            Log.e(">>","width:"+width+" height:"+height+" x:"+x+" y:"+y);
                            view.getLayoutParams().width = x;
                            view.getLayoutParams().height = y;
                            view.requestLayout();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                    }
                }

        }return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you this is android java code

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, there is a better way. A single TouchListener that handles everything.

Note: This approach also will also work for OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener, or any other listener that you would set on an Android view.